# Create table rows for multiple product details

Tags: php, html-table

I want to dynamicaly build a table which shows the product option name (like color and size etc.) and values (like red, large etc.) in rows.
It works just fine for one product, I get image and name and the option names, and in the second column the values.

Now I want to add the values of the next product  in the third column, but without the options name as it is allready printed by the first loop for the first product.
The next products image and name are showing ok, as I loop through the products.

All products have equal amount of product options.

The problem is, that the basic information, comes from one record in the database, but the options are stored as a record per option.

For one product:

```
  while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $product_data .= '<tr>
                        <th scope="row">' . $product['option_name']) . '</th>
                        <td>' . $product['option_value'] . '</td>
                      </tr>';
  }
```

How would I be able to add the option_values of an additional product to this row?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL Query in side `option_value()` function to get `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

```php
<?php
function option_value()
{
  while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$product['option_value']."'>".$product['option_name']."</option>";
   }
 }
 ?>


 <form>
  <select>
    <option disabled selected>select Category</option>
    <?php option_value();?>
  </select>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi Hein, I'm not building a combobox/pulldown menu.
I want to present the data in a table manner.